# How can I change the "a" vaule use the patato function?

Tags: python, function

```
def patato(a):
    a += 1
def tomato():
    a = 0 
    patato(a)
    print(a)
tomato()
```

**How can I change the "a" vaule use the patato function?**

Comment: you have to `return` - try it. (in both func)

Comment: You can't; that simply isn't how Python works.  One approach that would work would be to return the new value from `patato()`, and then do `a = patato(a)` to apply that change to `tomato`'s variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to the parameter variable doesn't affect the caller's variable, since variables are passed by value, not reference (in the case of mutable objects, the value is a reference to that object, but not a reference to the variable).

`patato` should return the new value, then you can assign it back to the variable.

```
def patato(a):
    return a + 1

def tomato():
    a = 0
    a = patato(a)
    print(a)

tomato()
```